# How to write this query with aggregation API MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

The query I am trying to achieve is this one:

```
test_db.find(
    {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'c': {
            '$nin': ['some_c']
        }
    }
)
```

Here, `c` is an array of elements.

I have an associated index for that:

```
xml_db.create_index(
    [
      ('a', 1),
      ('b', 1),
      ('c', 1)
    ],
    name='test_index',
    background=True
)
```

Now, for some reason, the query is very very slow. Even if I provide hint, it doesn't improve. However, `test_db.find({ 'a': a, 'b': b})` executes almost instantly.

Even, this runs really fast.

```
test_db.find(
    {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'c': {
            '$in': ['some_c']
        }
    }
)
```

Seems like `$nin` is the costly thing here.

Now, my plan is to match for the first two field, and then `filter` the result using the third condition. However, I am somehow struggling to structure the whole aggregation query with filter. Can someone please help on that?

Edit:

result of `explain`

```
'executionStages': {'advanced': 81265,
                     'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 59255,
                     'inputStage': {'advanced': 81265,
                                    'alreadyHasObj': 0,
                                    'docsExamined': 81273,
                                    'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 59075,
                                    'filter': {'$nor': [{'c': {'$eq': 'some_c'}}]},
                                    'inputStage': {'advanced': 81273,
                                                   'direction': 'forward',
                                                   'dupsDropped': 3,
                                                   'dupsTested': 81276,
                                                   'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 140,
                                                   'indexBounds': {'a': ['["some_val", '
                                                                                '"some_val"]'],
                                                                   'b': ['["fdfef5291233", '
                                                                                '"fdfef5291233"]'],
                                                                   'c': ['[MinKey, '
                                                                                     '"some_c")',
                                                                                     '("some_c", '
                                                                                     'MaxKey]']},
                                                   'indexName': 'test_index',
                                                   'indexVersion': 2,
                                                   'invalidates': 0,
                                                   'isEOF': 1,
                                                   'isMultiKey': True,
                                                   'isPartial': False,
                                                   'isSparse': False,
                                                   'isUnique': False,
                                                   'keyPattern': {'a': 1,
                                                                  'b': 1,
                                                                  'c': 1},
                                                   'keysExamined': 81278,
                                                   'multiKeyPaths': {'a': [],
                                                                     'b': [],
                                                                     'c': ['c']},
                                                   'nReturned': 81273,
                                                   'needTime': 4,
                                                   'needYield': 0,
                                                   'restoreState': 1381,
                                                   'saveState': 1381,
                                                   'seeks': 2,
                                                   'seenInvalidated': 0,
                                                   'stage': 'IXSCAN',
                                                   'works': 81278},
                                    'invalidates': 0,
                                    'isEOF': 1,
                                    'nReturned': 81265,
                                    'needTime': 12,
                                    'needYield': 0,
                                    'restoreState': 1381,
                                    'saveState': 1381,
                                    'stage': 'FETCH',
                                    'works': 81278},
                     'invalidates': 0,
                     'isEOF': 1,
                     'nReturned': 81265,
                     'needTime': 12,
                     'needYield': 0,
                     'restoreState': 1381,
                     'saveState': 1381,
                     'stage': 'PROJECTION',
                     'transformBy': {'_id': 0, 'feed_id': 0, 'original_url': 0},
                     'works': 81278},
 'executionSuccess': True,
 'executionTimeMillis': 59292,
 'nReturned': 81265,
 'totalDocsExamined': 81273,
 'totalKeysExamined': 81278}
```

Comment: Can you add the results from explain and what is the size of "test_index" ?
Since it is a compound index with an array field "c" , index size could become huge if collection size if huge.

Comment: @SharangChopra result of explain is added. Also though `c` is an array, it's not usually very big (length is usually 1 or 2, can be empty as well)

Comment: Try making an index for each field individually rather than an index for all 3 at once

Comment: $nin almost never uses index, maybe adding field "c" to the index is not helpful and it instead increases the index size. Can you create index on just "a" and "b" and check ? 

Reference - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: That explain output shows it spent 140ms identifying 81273 possible matches using the index, and then 58.9 seconds reading them from the storage.  I don't think aggregation will help with that.

Comment: @Joe but in reality in takes way more time than that. In fact if I find things with `$in`, it gets done pretty quickly. `$nin` is causing the problem here.

as @SharangChopra said, using all 3 for index isn't helping in this case, but even index with first two doesn't speedup the process.

Comment: Is the problem the query operator, or the number of documents being loaded?  Run explain for both queries and see what the difference really is.

Comment: @Joe problem is really the `$nin` operator. I have run explain on both of them, and there is a huge huge difference. ($nin doesn't even use the index). Now, I think only way to make it working is to do `find({'a': a, 'b': b}) - find({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': {'$in': {'some_c'}}})`, because both of them runs pretty fast. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @explain with `$nin` takes 18 minutes, whereas with `$in` it only takes 5 seconds.